# How to retrieve the link of the last post of a channel in telegram?

Tags: javascript, html, telegram

I want to put the last post of a telegram channel in a footer of a website and it get updated automatically i figured that i can use this for example ->
`<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?4" data-telegram-post="telegram/83" data-width="100%"></script>` But i want the link get updated asynchronously when another post get published in the channel.

any help would be highly appreciated.

for more information on post widget go [here](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/posts)

Comment: Are you admin of that channel?

Comment: yes I am the admin of the channel